# MikTeX | PDFLatex works, PDFTexfiy no longer does

Tags: pdftex, miktex, texify

Current primary setup is latest MikTeX, using WinEdt 9.1 as the front end (recently did a minor upgrade from WinEdt 8.xx -> 9.1. I know its not the most recent, but...).

At any rate, very simple problem. If I have a file (MWE below) that has no graphic, then MWE complies fine using either PDFLatex or PDFTexify (ctrl-alt-P). But, the moment I add a graphic (either .jpg or .png, makes no difference), the PDFLatex still works, but...PDFTexify now halts with a critical error that size/bound box of the image can't be determined.

Since this MWE compiled just fine at one point, it occurs to me that the options being passed to the MikTeX executables are no longer correct. Or, the executable WinEdt should be looking for has changed. Or...both.

For PDFLatex (which works), using pdflatex.exe as the executable, with --enable-write18 -synctex=1 %0 as the switches, and "%N%T" as parameters.

For PDFTexify, I have tried texify.exe using --pdf --tex-option=-enable-write18 as switches, and "%F" as the parameter (this used to work fine). Changing to pdflatex.exe as the executable doesn't work either.

Suggestions? Pointers to the obvious? I'm 99% sure the problem is some funky interaction with latest MikTeX executables, which executables WinEdt 9.1 is pointing at, and perhaps the switches and parameters set in WinEdt, but can't figure it out.

Here is a completely trivial MWE which probably isn't remotely necessary, but...

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

 \usepackage{graphicx}

 \begin{document}

 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce ut fermentum nisl, id imperdiet quam.  

 \vspace{1cm}
 Here is a figure.

 %\begin{figure}[ht]
 %\begin{center}
 % \includegraphics[keepaspectratio=true]{test.png}
 %\end{figure}

 \end{document}
```

Comment: I decided to 'experiment' -- and installed WinEdt 11.1 (latest). Sure enough, the default switches and parameters WinEdt 11.1 uses (which I'm guessing are 'correct' for latest MikTex binaries) are quite different than the ones I'd been using with WinEdt 9.1.

Comment: well your code contains an error, the \end{center} is missing, and texify is quite bad when it goes to error handling (I never use for this reason).

Comment: I accidentally deleted the \end{center} when I chopped down the MWE to post.  That wasn't the problem. The problem, as I surmised, is that the switches/parameters I had been using with WinEdt 9.1 no longer worked with the latest MikTeX binaries. I confirmed this by simply switching from WinEdt 9.1 -> WinEdt 11.1. Everything now compiles perfectly.